# Unclear why to use "A vuestros hijos" instead of "vuestros hijos"

Tags: traducción, gramática, preposiciones, sintaxis

I have the following sentence in English

> Do your children like to read?

Which translates to Spanish:

> ¿ A vuestros hijos les gusta leer?

To me it is unclear, why I have to use "**A** vuestros" in this case. Which grammatical rule is active here and are there other cases this rule applies as well?

Comment: I found another example which might fall into the same category: "Todos los padres quieren **a** sus hijos."

Comment: In that example, it's just a personal 'a', and has no English translation.

Comment: In my opinion the answer you are looking for is this *[personal a](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differences_between_Spanish_and_Portuguese#Personal_.22a.22)* mentioned by Flimzy and Arthaey.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remember that "gustar" means "to please" unlike the English "like" which essentially means "to be pleased by."  So what you're saying is:

> Is reading pleasing to your children?

When you state it this way, the obvious translation becomes:

> ¿Leer les gusta a vuestros hijos?

And then the necesity of the 'a' becomes more clear, as in this case it is a translation of the English "to."

An alternative way of translating this would be:

> ¿Vuestros hijos gustan de leer?

or

> ¿Vuestros hijos gustan de la lectura?

Comment: @DiegoMijelshon: Is your update that proper grammar, or a slang/regional usage? It looks completely wrong to me :) (But you probably know better than I do.)

Comment: It is proper grammar. "gustar de" is an idiom that can be used in the same way as "like" in English.

Comment: @DiegoMijelshon: And in that case, you conjugate 'gustar' for the person, not the object being liked, eh?

Comment: @Flimzy: exactly. "Cuando era adolescente, gustaba de la musica punk" or "Cuando era adolescente, me gustaba la musica punk" or "Cuando era adolescente, la musica punk me gustaba [a mi]", they all translate to "When I was a teeenager, I liked [or *used to like*] punk music"

Comment: @DiegoMijelshon: I'll have to test that construct here and see if I get strange looks :)

Comment: @Flimzy keep in mind the alternative form is more used in writing

Comment: @DiegoMijelshon: Ahh, good to know, thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Your two examples are actually different phenomena.

Ex. 1) **¿A vuestros hijos les gusta leer?**

Consider the following statements:

- Me gusta leer.
- Me gusta leer a mí.
- A mí, me gusta leer.

You can always add the *a mí* for emphasis. Similarly, you can add an "a [person]" to clarify who the pronoun refers to, in the more ambiguous case of *les*.

Ex. 2) **Todos los padres quieren a sus hijos.**

This is a different case: [the personal *a*](http://www.braser.com/spanish-learning/spanish-personal-a.html), which requires the word *a* before a direct object that is a person.